Is there a way to get the nth sibling (element) of an element? (NOT the nth child of the parent element)
I have a grid with an unknown number of rows and a variable number of columns. I set the number of columns by declaring a constant.* I detect a key combo to move focus from an element in the grid whose position is unknown; it could be any of the grid's child elements (images in this case). The idea is to move focus to the image either directly above or below.
To do this, I need to get the nth sibling element, either previous or next, from the focused element, where n is the number of columns.
I can't use parentNode.querySelector(':nth-child(…)') since I don't know the relationship of the focused element to the starting index (:first-child).
*Since this is a web component, the constant is set by declaring an attribute on the component.
Is there a JavaScript method to handle such cases?

You can count children of parent until you find the original node. That's how you can find nth position.


function getNthPosition(node) {

  const parent = node.parentElement;

  
  // var nodes = parent.querySelectorAll(":scope > *");
  var nodes = parent.children;
  for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {

    if (nodes[i] === node) {
      return i + 1
    }
  }
  return -1;
}

document.querySelectorAll("button").forEach(function(button) {
  button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log("position", getNthPosition(button))
  })
})
<div class="parent">
  <button>click</button>
  <button>click</button>
  <button>click</button>
  <button>click</button>
</div>




Thanks; I did solve this with let prevFocused = document.activeElement; let parent      = prevFocused.parentNode; let prevIndex   = Array.prototype.indexOf.call(parent.children, prevFocused); which gave me the position of the focused element; from there I used a lot of algebra to determine where to place focus (because focus cycles from bottom to top row & vice-versa if the image is on the last or top row, and sometimes the last row is shorter than the other rows).
In any case, you answered my question: Is there a JavaScript method to handle such cases?

No, there is no DOM method that does this directly. However, you can

iterate .previous|next(Element)Sibling for the given number of times:
function getNthElementSibling(el, n) {
  while (el && n > 0) {
    el = el.nextElementSibling;
    n--;
  }
  while (el && n < 0) {
    el = el.previousElementSibling;
    n++;
  }
  return el;
}

(Use .nextSibling and .previousSibling if you want to take non-element nodes into account)
look up the element's index in its parent's child (element) nodes (see Finding DOM node index, JavaScript DOM: Find Element Index In Container) and then return the respective child after index arithmetic:
function getNthElementSibling(el, n) {
  const siblings = Array.from(el.parentNode.children);
  return siblings[siblings.indexOf(el) + n];
}

(Use .childNodes if you want to take non-element nodes into account)


Thanks; I did solve this with let prevFocused = document.activeElement; let parent      = prevFocused.parentNode; let prevIndex   = Array.prototype.indexOf.call(parent.children, prevFocused); which gave me the position of the focused element; from there I used a lot of algebra to determine where to place focus (because focus cycles from bottom to top row & vice-versa if the image is on the last or top row, and sometimes the last row is shorter than the other rows).
In any case, you answered my question: Is there a JavaScript method to handle such cases?
